# android alarm manager repeat every two years

Tags: android, alarmmanager, repeat

In my android application i need to show notification to user every two years at 09.00. I used the following method but did not work exactly

```
AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 30 * 6 * 4
```

and the following code is my full alarm manager

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {



    private AlarmManager AlarmManager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        AlarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(2018,2,9,9,0);


        AlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 30 * 6 * 4, pendingIntent);

    }
}
```

Comment: You should rethink the app logic. That alarm wont be there after 2 years.

Comment: @ADM A program to remind you when to change the water purifier filter, Filters must be replaced every two years

Comment: Alarms do not survive device reboots. Alarms also get removed when your app is uninstalled/updated. you are better off doing something on a server and notifying the device with FCM. There is no way a 2 year alarm is going to be there because the user will probably have uninstalled the app by then or got a new device

Comment: @tyczj It was a good answer ,I did not know what it was FCM But now I searched and I understood something I think I'll solve my problem Can you introduce a FCM sample alarm Notifications source code from github